# .net c sharp Console Application : timeout

Tags: .net, ado.net, timeout, enterprise-library

I am creating a console application using Enterprise Library my code is something  like this

```
 DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(command);
```

this actually calling a SP which take 10-15 minutes to complete , so my come throws a time-out error.

Any idea how to overcome this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before calling the ExecuteDataSet method, set [`command.CommandTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) to however many seconds you're willing to wait before actually timing out. For example, if you're willing to wait 2 hours for the query to complete, set `command.CommandTimeout` to 7200.

You can set the `CommandTimeout` property to zero for an infinite timeout, but this is generally a bad idea since if something goes really wrong, you don't want to hang forever.